# How to change the color of few nodes of treeview in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need to programmatically change the color of nodes in treeview. Is there any solution with asp.net or jquery? 
PS: I am binding the treeview nodes on demand.

```
 private void BindTreeViewControl()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt = GetData();

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
                    root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;
                    root.ShowCheckBox = true;
                      child.PopulateOnDemand = Convert.ToUInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Count"]) > 0;                    TreeViewDemo.Nodes.Add(root);
                }
              }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw Ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In tree view item data bound you can set forcolor

Comment: could you please provide me some code or links that I can refer.

Comment: what's the purpose? see events of treeView here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview_events.aspx

Comment: how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/763139/1358004

Comment: Something which might help you **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219602/how-to-change-color-in-asp-netc-if-treenode-checked**

Comment: @Prashant Lakhlani purpose is to distinguish between the nodes based on some criteria.

Comment: @huMpty duMpty my requirement is not about selected node, at the time of creating rows I need to change the color of node based on some criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treenode color can be changed by setting node text

`<div class='myclass' style='color: red'>Node Text</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Dee,

[TreeNodeDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodedatabound.aspx) would be an appropriate choice for you. It occurs when a data item is bound to node and you can access all properties of a node there and set properties where you want.

Comment: There is no property available to set color, css for a node.

Comment: I have updated answer, you said you want to update color, so I think there are background color or text color that you can update and both can be done using treenode object. see my updated answer above

Comment: I am looking for asp.net treeview. The link you have shared is for windows treeview.

Comment: right my bad, you have to  extend it, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17505/Adding-custom-attributes-and-applying-CSS-to-nodes